# Circular dependence and many references to the same object

Tags: design, architecture, programming-practices

[image]

I have tried to design a class diagram for my first game. But then I realized that there are some ugly parts.

First, there is reference from `StateSystem` to `State` and from `State` to `StateSystem`. The `StateSystem` object contains references to `State` instances and one of them is always current.  `StateSystem` calls it's update and render functions. But every instance of `State` also has to have a reference back to `StateSystem`, so it can change state to another one. I'd like to know how to avoid the circular dependence in this case.

Secondly, I don’t know where to hold reference(s) to the `Input` object. Generally, all classes which belong to the UI (green classes) need a reference to the same instance (only existing instance) of `Input` due to mouse collision detection.  `Input` contains stored information about pressed keys, mouse coordinates and so on. Should I store the reference in every object that needs it?

Moreover, what about `TextureManager` class? The only thing it does is store `Texture` instances via string IDs (and preparing it for OpenGL) and when needed, it returns a texture according to a given ID. Should I consider using, for example, the Builder pattern and let only the "director" object own the texture manager and create concrete textures for objects?

Comment: There's a couple ways to idealogically break the cycle.  You can decide that "State" is completely passive and only "StateSystem" can modify it.  Therefore, "State" has no outgoing references.  Alternatively, you can use an interface for the StateSystem, and define the few calls that State can make on the StateSystem in the interface.  Whether you provide the StateSystem object or a proxy to it does not change the behavior.

Comment: The first option seems not to be possible for me. The "State" cannot be passive in this way, because different states change the current state in different situations. Some states contain buttons for this purpose, some states check keys etc. The dependency inversion using interface limites the usage of StateSystem to a few methods, but the reference is still here. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: I don't understand the need for State objects to be in charge of changing which one of them is current.  This seems to be creating your issue.  What about this is important for your design?

Comment: Hmm, that's true. There is no reason to make states responsible for changing current state, because the buttons, which really decide about that, are stored deeper in structure of components, so I would unnecessarily create another circular dependences. But buttons need the power to call StateSystem.changeState, don't they? So the answer is to make something like C#'s delegate which is equal to make interface with just few methods in it as Berin Loritsch suggested.

Comment: Or second option I can think of is to return the fact, that state have to be  changed through return values of method update. But there is a problem, what if there were another informations, that has to be returned and second one is already mentioned nested structure, I think it would be huge mess in the code, so how do you mean that State (or Button or whatever) can by completely passive?